# Multi-select with optgroups in knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout-2.0

i have a question about KnockoutJS and the multiselect with groups.
I have this structure:

```
var Contact = function (contact) {
    var self = this;
    self.idContact = contact.IdContact;
    self.displayName = contact.DisplayName;
    self.mails = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contact.Emails, function (mail) {
        return { mail: mail };
    }));
};

var Quote = function (quote) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(quote.ProviderContacts, function (contact) {
        return new Contact(contact);
    }));
};
```

and the main ModelView has a Quote and the mainContactsList.
Then i have the select:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: contacts, value: $root.quote.contacts" multiple="multiple">
                    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: displayName, value: idContact}, foreach: mails">
                        <option data-bind="text: mail, value: mail"></option>
                    </optgroup>
                 </select>
```

So.. the thing is that i don't know how to do to save the Quote with only the contacts i select and the emails selected.
I mean, the select looks like this:

```
[John Doe]
---- john@doe.com
---- john2@doe.com--->selected by client
[Jane Doe]
---- jane@doe.com--->selected by client
```

so, in my Quote i need to have, the contact list with JohnDoe and the mail john2@doe.com and the contact Jane Doe and the mail jane@doe.com.

I hope you understand my problem and have a solution :)

Thanks!